# I would like to only allow one entry for a row in a model in Django, is this possible?

Tags: python, django

Im building an inventory management web app (stock room manager).

I have a model class:

```
class location(models.Model):
    loc_room = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    loc_section = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loc_shelf = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
```

And a model class:

```
class box(models.Model):    
    box_contents = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True) 
    location_id = models.ForeignKey('location', null=True)
```

Is there a way that I could limit the number of boxes per location to only one entry? Its for a store room that only has one box per 'location'.

E.g 
What I would like: At location Room: A, Section 1, Shelf 2 there should only ever be 1 x box with contents: 'Screwdriver, drill, shampoo'.

E.g What is currently the case: At location Room: A, Section 1, Shelf 2 = 1 x box with contents: 'Screwdriver, drill, shampoo' ALSO 1 x box wiith contents: 'Towel rack, cups'

At the moment, employees can add as many boxes per location as they like but I would like to limit this to one box as each location can physically only contain one box.

Comment: Can a box only be in one location? In other words, if there's another box containing 'Screwdriver, drill, shampoo' in another location, would that be another instance of box, or the same one?

Comment: The keyword to google for is "contraint" which normally refers to a "rule" in the database that limits the data in some way. Most known are "foreign key contraints" which make sure that an id in a foreign key column actually refers to an id that exists. I'm sure some django guru can tell you how exactly to implement this contraint in your case.

Comment: Hi Daniel, a box can only be in one location, thats correct. If another box contained 'Screwdriver, drill, shampoo' it would be another instance of a box

Comment: syntonym - thats useful information to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the relational model normalisation rules, if you can only have one single instance of B for a given instance of A **and** all A have one instance of B (1 to 1 relationship), then A and B are really the same entity, so you should then move `box_contents` to `Location` and remove the `Box` model.

If A can have 0 or 1 B (and B only belong to a single A), you can either do as above but allow `null` for `box_contents`, in which case `null` means there's no box for this location while the empty string means "there's a box but it's empty" or - if you find it impractical or have other reasons to want to keep a distinct `Box` model - put a `unique` contraint on `Box.location` - and since you're using django, use a `models.OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey` field.

As a side note :

1/ the convention is to use `CamelCase` for class names (`Location' and`Box`, not`location`and`box`) - this makes life easier when it comes to naming a`Location` instance

2/ the `ForeignKey` (or `OneToOneField`) in `Box` should really be named `location` - because when using `box.location`, you *will* get a `Location` object, not the underlying `location_id`.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, thats answered my question and also given me some food for thought regarding combining the two models.. interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Since a box can only be in one location and a location can only have one box, you should have a OneToOneField rather than a ForeignKey.

(Note also, you shouldn't use the suffix `_id` for your field names; the Django field refers to the entire related object.)

```
class box(models.Model):    
    box_contents = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True) 
    location = models.OneToOneField('location', null=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you posted your answer just a minute after Bruno, I can't accept more than one answer unfortunately and I can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation but your answer works too

Comment: Thanks for the tips with the field name too, I will implement this